# Restart app after crash using Crashlytics

Tags: android

Is it possible to auto-restart app after crash using Crashlytics? Unfortunately there is nothing about that topic in docs. I defined my own exception handler which is restarting app, but when i use it crash logs are not sent.

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom exception handler you can call `Craslytics.logException(exception);`.

```
public class MyExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        //you should also log the exception to logcat
        Log.e(TAG, "UncaughtException", exception);

        try {
            //log to crashlytics
            Crashlytics.logException(exception);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uncaughtException: Crashlytics not initialized, cannot send logs.");
        }
        //exit with error code 1 (0 is normal program termination, 
        //which here is not the case)
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

One thing worth noting is that `Crashlytics.logError(...)` logs exceptions as "non-fatal". So I usually wrap them so I can differentiate non-fatal exceptions from actual fatal ones.

So:

```
Crashlytics.logException(exception);
```

becomes:

```
//wrap the original exception to your custom 'fatal' exception type.
FatalException fatalException = new FatalException(originalException);
//log with Crashlytics
Crashlytics.logException(fatalException);
```

Sample from an open source app [here](https://github.com/openstreetcam/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/telenav/osv/application/OSVApplication.java#L96).

Comment: Making `FatalException` not working anymore. Its constructor not accept `originalException`. Any idea?